# How can I assign the value of a char array to a uint8_t array?

Tags: programming, c++, array, arduino-yun

I have a char array variable that has a value.
I need to send this value through LoRa. The library I use for the LoRa implementation accepts an array of uint8_t. How can I pass the value of a char[] to a uint8_t[] variable (and the opposite)?

```
if (Udp.parsePacket()) {
  int udp_received = Udp.available();
  char udp_buffer[udp_received + 1];
  Udp.read(udp_buffer, udp_received);
  udp_buffer[udp_received] = '\0';

  uint8_t udp_to_lora[] = "???";
  rf95.send(udp_to_lora, sizeof(udp_to_lora));
  rf95.waitPacketSent();

}
```

I need to pass the **udp_buffer** to **uint8_t udp_to_lora[]**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have a compiler at hand, but you can cast the array  as a `char` and `uint8_t` are similar in size:

```
rf95.send((char*) udp_to_lora, sizeof(udp_to_lora));
```

Comment: How could it be so easy? Thanks! But help me understand. What's the purpose of the dereference asterisk in this cast?

Comment: Same the other way round: `rf95.send((uint8_t*)udp_buffer, udp_received);`

Comment: a `char` is a character, a `char *` is a POINTER to a character. However, an array of characters is the same, as it points to the first character of a text.

Comment: "What's the purpose of the dereference asterisk in this cast?" It's in the context. In a type specification (which a cast is) the '*' is part of the type, where it means "pointer to". In a value, it is the dereference operator and means "the value of what [thing] points to", or more literally, "the value contained in the memory location(s) whose address is the value of [thing]". Locations is plural because Arduino memory, being byte addressable, most variables are multi-byte.

Comment: dereference is `*a`